# How can I make dragonbone armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting

Here's my question (well questions):

1. How do you make dragon scale armor in D&D?
2. How do you upgrade your smithing level (like, what level to make it)?
3. What materials do you need to make dragon scale armor?

Comment: Yup, I edited the tag to signify that (it's where we are used to seeing it), but I still have the other question of what you mean by smithing level. Or, to broaden it, what are you using as a reference for understanding the game?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119323/discussion-on-question-by-rave-dragonbone-armor-and-smithing-upgradesdungeonsd).

Answer (score 3):

#### Dragon Scale Mail requires 25 weeks, 20,000 gold, and ingredients left up to the DM's discretion.

[Dragon Scale Mail](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-scale-mail) is a very rare magic item. Consulting the [Magic Items crafting tables](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, we see that crafting this item requires Smith's Tools (and proficiency therewith), 25 weeks, and 20,000 gold pieces to complete.

Additionally, these rules suggest that the DM make a quest out of this:

> Creating a magic item requires more than just time, effort, and materials. It is a long-term process that involves one or more adventures to track down rare materials and the lore needed to create the item.

The Magic Item Ingredients table recommends a quest to kill an appropriate creature with a Challenge Rating of 13-18. Since we are making mail from Dragon Scales, we will likely be hunting an adult dragon of some color, many of which can be found on [this list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=6&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=17&filter-cr-max=22&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=) generated through a DNDBeyond search.

Also there are no smithing levels in D&D. D&D 5e uses "Proficiency", in this case, we need proficiency with Smith's Tools. The rules for Tool Proficiency state:

> A tool helps you to do something you couldn't otherwise do, such as craft or repair an item, forge a document, or pick a lock. Your race, class, background, or feats give you proficiency with certain tools. Proficiency with a tool allows you to add your proficiency bonus to any ability check you make using that tool. Tool use is not tied to a single ability, since proficiency with a tool represents broader knowledge of its use. For example, the DM might ask you to make a Dexterity check to carve a fine detail with your woodcarver's tools, or a Strength check to make something out of particularly hard wood.

Comment: Also might be worth noting that the crafting rules (both in DMG and Xanathar's) are optional. Those times/costs/requirements may be different at any table.